how can i change a widget value depending on Combobox selected if widgets are in one def , callback function is another def in Python
from tkinter import ttk,messagebox
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import customtkinter as CTk
import cnx # database connection

def getcombovalue(event,x):
    selection = event.widget.get()
    print(event)
    for city in x:
        if city["city"]==selection:
            countryId = city["countryId"]
            result = getcountry(countryId)
        print(result)
        country_label['text']=result  # here is the problem

def getcountry(cntryId):
    print("simdi getcountry deyiz ")
    query = (f'SELECT country FROM countries WHERE countryId={cntryId}')
    result = cnx.Database.gettableinfo(query)
    return result

def Employee_New(self,master):
        
        
    self.title_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Customer Information", font=("Helvetica", 16))
    self.title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        
    # Customer Name
    # Email
    # Phone Number
    # Address
    # City
    city_label = ttk.Label(self, text="City:")
    city_label.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
    query = ('Select cityId, city, countryId from cities')
    result = cnx.Database.gettableinfo(query)
    
    choice = StringVar(self)
    result_for_combobox = [city["city"] for city in result] 
    self.city_entry = ttk.Combobox(self,values =result_for_combobox,textvariable=choice)
    self.city_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    self.city_entry.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>',lambda event, x=result: getcombovalue(event,x))
       
    # Country
    country_label = ttk.Label(self, text="Country:")
    country_label.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=tk.W)
     
    country_entry = ttk.Combobox(self)
    country_entry.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)

    # Notes
    # Submit Button


#everything goes fine , until i choose value in city combobox , i can not return the value to #country widget which is depending on the city widget
#i have CRM.py in which i am creatin window, Menubar,frames.. i am trying to separate all the forms #i will create depending on menu selection in forms.py
#as long as i will use city and country connection and comboboxselect in other forms as well i #created separate defs for them.
